# How to lookup a ip of a domain via a specific DNS?

Tags: networking, server, dns

I am familiar with `nslookup` and `host` commands, but if, for example, my default DNS is a non-Chinese DNS, and I do a `host -t NS weimobdc.com`, it will return `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.

I want to look it up through a specific DNS, like `host -DNS 114.114.114.114 weimobdc.com`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dig` command

```
 dig -t [option] [name] [server]
```

Example

```
 dig -t any askununtu.com 8.8.8.8
 dig -t any askubuntu.com 8.8.4.4
```

More you can find [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)

or you can use `host`

```
host name server
```

Example

```
host askubuntu.com 8.8.8.8
```

More you can find [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/host)

If you have problem to send query to some dns server you can try make connection to that server with command

```
nc -v -u 10.10.10.10 53

nc - netcat command
v - verbose
u - udp protocol
10.10.10.10 - dns server ip
53 - port
```

Output will be something like this if work

```
nc -v -u 10.10.10.10 53
Connection to 10.10.10.10 53 port [udp/domain] succeeded!
```

Maybe is not allowed to send query except to you internet provider dns server. You must check with your ISP

Comment: `dig -t any weimobdc.com 114.114.114.114` this works

Answer (score 0):

Since you're familiar with `nslookup`:

```
nslookup weimobdc.com 114.114.114.114
```

Comment: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached